# SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 over ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

i making ajax call my code looks like this

```
        var Data = {
        name              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
        email             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
        phoneno           : $('input[name=phoneno]').val(),
        password          : $('input[name=password]').val(),
    };
    var data = JSON.stringify(Data);
$.ajax({
        url: "/registeruser",   
        type: "POST",      
        data:  data,      
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(response)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
        {
          console.log('responsee........', response);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
            console.log('handle errpe message',errorMessage); // Optional
        },
    });
```

i get an error on my server side nodejs
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

my express route code

```
exports.registeruserController = function(req,res,next){
    console.log('sdasdasdasdasd');
 console.log('request of the user to register',req.body);
}
```

Comment: Can you share what's in the `data` variable that you are passing to the server?

Comment: var Data = {
            'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
            'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
            'phoneno'           : $('input[name=phoneno]').val(),
            'password'          : $('input[name=password]').val(),
        };

Comment: Can you also add a line `console.log(data)` before you make your `$.ajax` request and post the results in the question as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` is not JSON.

It is an object which is being implicitly converted to a string:

```js
var data = { for: "example" };
var what_you_are_sending = "" + data;
console.log(what_you_are_sending);
```

The server is trying to parse it as JSON. The `[` is the start of an array. The `o` is an error. Then it stops.

---

You need to convert the object to JSON with `JSON.stringify`.

```js
var data = JSON.stringify({ for: "example" });
var what_you_should_send = "" + data;
console.log(what_you_should_send);
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem just use.

```
JSON.stringify(res.data)
```